# Intent service or Service for servers in android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice

For my program I am developing a small **udp server** in android that listen to the short strings and will **call the notification manager**.

the server using readUTF() method to receive messages. and this server has to run even the application is killed.

For that which one will be better. **service or intent service**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use service for listening continuously.

You need to start service in foreground so that It will not be killed when user remove app  from recent task.